# Foundation 3 menu suffers click-through on iPad

Tags: ipad, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a site implemented with Zurb foundation 3, for example http://www.finecooking.com/videos/

If you view this on an iPad today, in **landscape** view I currently have it using the desktop  menus. However, some menu items do not seem to register taps correctly; either no navigation happens or the banner ad below takes the tap instead of the menu item.

From the above link, try using the "how-to" menu item to go to the "how to main page".  Does not work, iPad 3 using Safari 6 and Safari 7.

If I can't get this to work, I will need to set the iPad to use the mobile menu, even on landscape.